# How do i retain parent values when using Save & New Button

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have enabled the SaveAndNew button using Ribbon Workbench but users are requesting that the related forms retain certain values from the parent record when a new form is created. Is there a way using JS which can getValues prior to OnSave and SetValues OnLoad (without erroring the standard Save/Save&Close functions).

I am using Dynamics 365 Online - The entities in question already have 1:n relationships but after the first form create, the parent mappings are lost. Please help...

Comment: Can you show us a minimal code snippet so that other users can help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

From the SDK (V9.0):

```
var entityFormOptions = {};
entityFormOptions["entityName"] = "contact";

// Set default values for the Contact form
var formParameters = {};
formParameters["firstname"] = "Sample";
formParameters["lastname"] = "Contact";
formParameters["fullname"] = "Sample Contact";
formParameters["emailaddress1"] = "contact@adventure-works.com";
formParameters["jobtitle"] = "Sr. Marketing Manager";
formParameters["donotemail"] = "1";
formParameters["description"] = "Default values for this record were set     programmatically.";

// Open the form.
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions, formParameters).then(
function (success) {
        console.log(success);
},
function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

//Old versions:
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("contact", null, formParameters);
```